# Processwire pagination

Tags: pagination, processwire

I'm developing a news section and it's my first time working with ProcessWire.
I have the following code:

```
                <?php
                $articles           = $page->children("limit=2");

                if(!empty($articles)):        
                    foreach($articles as $article):
            ?>

                <div class="news-article">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-9 columns">
                            <a href="<?php echo $article->url;?>"><h3 style="padding-bottom: 15px;"><?php echo $article->title;?></h3></a>
                            <?php echo substr($article->body, 0, 375); ?>...
                            <p><a href="<?php echo $article->url;?>">Read full story &gt;</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-3 columns">
                            <img src="<?php echo $article->images->url . $article->images; ?>" style="margin: 20px 0 20px 0;" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <style>
                .news-article {
                    padding:                20px 0 0 0;
                    margin:                 20px 0 20px 0;
                }
                </style>

            <?php 
                    endforeach;
                else:
                    echo "<h3>No articles found</h3>";
                endif;

                $pagination = $articles->renderPager();
                echo $pagination;
            ?>
```

My problem is the pagination correctly displays 2 page links, but clicking the second page displays page 2 with the first 2 articles.

I'm assuming I have to modify my article display code to factor in what page I'm on, but I'm unsure how to do so.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Graham

Answer (score 6):

Please head back to the [official pagination documentation](http://processwire.com/api/modules/markup-pager-nav/) first and make sure to read through it carefully again.

I suppose you have missed to enable Pagination in your template:

> Determine what template(s) you want to use pagination with. Go to Admin > Setup > Templates > [Your Template] > URLs, and check the box for: Allow Page Numbers. Save.

[image: Enable pagination for a template]

Now you should be able to use your code without any problems for this particular template. It is automatically taken care of every time use use `$pages->find()` with a `limit` argument >1.